# Macbook 5,1 with Ubuntu 14.04 goes black after waking from Suspend

Tags: login, suspend, macbook

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook 5,1 and when I close the lid to suspend it for any amount of time my computer just goes black or freezes at the login screen. On the few occasions this hasn't happened, the computer needed more than 10 minutes being left alone to start back up normally. Has anyone else figured out a solution to this problem?

I have looked at most of the questions about this, but no one has posted a solution that has worked for me.

Comment: Similar issue for me at my old noname notebook. I guess it has to do with my graphics card (nVidia GeForce Go 7400) that seems to be fried. I entirely disabled suspending for all users. Only did not find a solution to prevent it from suspending from the login screen :-(